# Q: MOSFET not providing correct supply voltage

Tags: mosfet

I dont work much with mosfets so I dont really know how to go about this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftyOnu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So pretty much I have the circuit above, What's happening is that the Source of the mosfet is outputing around 3.3V and not close to 5V. I understand there will be resistance as RDS(on) however its 0.200ohms. Shouldn't make it 3.3V.

EDIT:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fafkOi.png)</sup>

So I tried this configuration, what happens now is that:

1. I am still not getting ~5V at the Drain
2. The mosfet gets real hot
3. Now the gate voltage is not even 5V, but once I take out the mosfet, 5V returns back at the output of the comparator.

Comment: If you edit the circuit to use less horizontal space, it will probably be easier to read in the preview image in your post.

Comment: I edited the schematic because I forgot the pull up resistor.

Comment: Your second circuit is making the MOSFET try to short +5V to ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to turn on fully, the gate to source voltage as to be above some threshold.  When you have an enhancement-mode MOSFET wired as a source follower (like that one), the source will have to be below the gate.

You could get the effect that I think you want by using a P-channel FET and reversing the sense of the MCP6548.

Comment: I dont understand what is that though. Did I do something wrong or its the limitations of my mosfet

Comment: It's a limitation of nearly **all** MOSFET's.  That's just how they work, other than depletion mode devices, which are only slightly more common than hen's teeth.  The gate voltage simply has to be higher than the source voltage for the FET to conduct -- it's how the device works.

Comment: Is there a better way to essentially turn on the op amp

Comment: Well, you could take my suggestion about a P-channel MOSFET!  Or use a PNP junction transistor and a suitable base resistor.  Why the resistance to a P-channel FET?

Comment: I am just curious how does a PNP work better than a N

Comment: A P-channel FET has the same limitation about Vgs as an N-channel FET.  But because it's of opposite polarity, now you're connecting the source to +5V and the drain to your load -- so putting 5V between gate and source is just a matter of pulling the gate to ground.  Note that you *do* need to make sure that your comparator pulls its output all the way to it's +V power rail, or that you've provisioned the circuit with a pull-up resistor.

Comment: See what I dont understand, whats happening in the second circuit, for some reason my comparator is no longer pulling to the 5V it was before, even in the first circuit it was. But the mosfet is just outputing around 3.3V?

Comment: What's happening to your "5V" supply when you turn on the MOSFET?

Comment: I believe I want to say its 5V, but what if it isnt. Its regulated it thought. Its one of those Apples Iphone charger one

Answer (score 0):

MCP6548 has an open drain output. So it can only pull the gate of M low, it can't drive a high voltage onto the gate.

In addtion, RFP12N10 has a Vgs(th) of 1 to 2 V, so even if you do pull the gate to 5 V, in order for current to flow through the channel the source will be at 4 V or lower.

Comment: That makes one wonder why the circuit works at all!

Comment: Interesting, I wouldnt expect it to go that low. How do people go around this problem then?

Comment: @Pllsz. you could use a PMOS as in Tim's answer. Or use a dedicated power switch device. Or boost the gate drive voltage above 5 V. Or use the NMOS as a low-side switch instead of high side. Or...

Comment: Oh no, isn't complete I am just stuck at this stage

The purpose right now, is to essentially "sense" specific voltage peaks of an audio signal and amplify when the threshold is to low, and if its low amplify it and if its not low I was going to have a buffer just to pass on the signal.

The N channel was to be a gate if the signal is low and needs amplification
and P channel for when the signal doesnt need amplification 

After this stage was going to be a pre-amp stage with a series of filters to signal condition.

Comment: I forgot to mention the MOSFET gets hot over quite some time, and I dont understand why this MOSFEt isn't doing what its suppose to do? In the datasheet it says RDS(on) 0.200 when VG = 5V? Thought this was a logic mosfet and what if I change it from source to the drain? and how can a PNP help out?

Comment: Rds(on) is 0.2 ohms when Vg**s** is 5 V. Not when Vg is 5 V. In this case you want the source to be at 5 V, so the gate must be at 10 V to have Vgs = 5 V. The device has no idea what the ground potential is if you don't connect at least one of its terminals to ground.

Comment: Oh I see, my Vs is floating isnt?

Comment: new changes that I made

Comment: @Pilsz, please don't change the question after people have taken the trouble to answer.